# JUnit tests with Hypersonic database

Tags: java, database, junit, hsqldb

Can anyone guide me to an url or resource where I can find how to write JUnit tests with a Hypersonic Database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [search on JUnit and HSQLDB](http://swik.net/hsqldb+junit) should give you enough links to get started. It also provides links for integrating HSQLDB for unit testing with other frameworks like Spring and Hibernate. For beginners ["Using HSQLDB For Unit Testing Database Access Code"](http://tech.shopzilla.com/2010/01/using-hsqldb-for-unit-testing-database-access-code/) is a good read.